# AngularJS2: Include JQuery into application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

after a good hour of googling I still haven't found out how to properly include JQuery (or any normal JS file for that matter) into my AnuglarJS application, how would I go over this?

Comment: Why not in the HTML itself with <script>?

Comment: why do u need to include jQuery if you are using AngularJS. and anyways u can include any script in your HTML.

Comment: it appears that this does not work for some reason

Comment: `does not work for some reason` - reproduce your issue in plnk or jsfiddle

Comment: @paritosh because I'm working with a CSS libary that includes a JS libary that works with JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS provides jqLite, which is a jQuery-like library that provides a subset of jQuery functionality.But it doesnt work if you include jQuery in your app. You should check this out for how to integrating  angular and jQuery
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2752-using-jquery-instead-of-jqlite-in-angularjs.htm